# How to emit a string without quotes using yaml-cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp, emit

I know that by default yamp-cpp emits strings without quotes but, if there are brackets in the string it always emit it with double quotes.

```
YAML::Emitter out;
// ...
const std::string myStr = "[0, 0, 1]"
out << myStr;
```

In the above example I get in the file: "[0, 0, 1]" when I want [0, 0, 1]

Do you know how to solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason yaml-cpp is quoting your string is that if it didn't, you'd be emitting a sequence, not a scalar. If you want to emit the sequence `[0, 0, 1]`, then you can do so:

```
out << YAML::BeginSeq << 0 << 0 << 1 << YAML::EndSeq;
```

But you simply *can't* emit the text `[0, 0, 1]` as a plain scalar, since it's not!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
YAML::Emitter out;
// ...
const std::string myStr = "[0, 0, 1]"
out << YAML::Load(myStr);
```

or this:

```
out.WriteStreamable(myStr);
```